# What are the systemd dependencies of ntpd?

Tags: systemd, ntp

My ntptime is showing error code 5 when the system starts. Restarting the ntpd through systemctl fixes this. Waiting a few minutes also seems to fix this. I have verified that ntpq shows that ntpd is talking to my intended server. This may be caused by another issue, but I think I'll take this time to ask a more general-purpose question.

Does anybody know which systemd dependencies are required for ntpd to work? I would love to see a minimum working example ntpd.service file from a system whose ntptime shows great success on system start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your dependencies of a systemd unit with:

```
 systemctl list-dependencies ntp
```

That command was found by reviewing `man systemctl`.

Comment: I don't think that's the answer I need. I know how to search my current dependencies, but I need to know which services are required for in order to make it work.

Comment: The dependencies *are* the services required to make it work. I'm not sure what else you are asking.

Comment: I can modify the After and Requires vars in the service file to add or subtract services. Some of them may be unnecessary, or I may be missing some services. If, however, systems can be expected to run with what is shipped with the vanilla ntpd.service file, then I guess I have my answer and can try debugging elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, you should expect that the `ntp.service` shipped with the system works.  If my answer was helpful, please consider upvoting or accepting it.